# MultiIndex from irregular tuple of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following tuples

```
tups = zip(list('AAAABBBB'), zip(list('aabbaabb'), list('cdcdcdcd')))

tups

[('A', ('a', 'c')),
 ('A', ('a', 'd')),
 ('A', ('b', 'c')),
 ('A', ('b', 'd')),
 ('B', ('a', 'c')),
 ('B', ('a', 'd')),
 ('B', ('b', 'c')),
 ('B', ('b', 'd'))]
```

I'd like to create a pandas MultiIndex from them

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(32).reshape(4, 8),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tups))
```

But I get tuples in a second level.  How do I get all three levels?

```
print df

       A                           B                     
  (a, c) (a, d) (b, c) (b, d) (a, c) (a, d) (b, c) (b, d)
0      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
1      8      9     10     11     12     13     14     15
2     16     17     18     19     20     21     22     23
3     24     25     26     27     28     29     30     31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to flatten your tuples.  I did it as follows

```
new_tups = [(a, b, c) for a, (b, c) in tups]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(32).reshape(4, 8),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_tups))
```

[image]